# method to create variables

Tags: python, tkinter

Im trying to have my method assemble buttons depending on what "list" i select,
What would be the best way on going about to do so?

from tkinter import *
    root = Tk()

```
frame = Frame(root)
frame.grid()

b1 = Button(frame, textvariable='1')
a1 = b1.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='w')
b2 = Button(frame, text='2')
a2 = b2.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky='w')
b3 = Button(frame, text='3')
a3 = b3.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky='w')
b4 = Button(frame, text='4')
a4 = b4.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky='w')
b5 = Button(frame, text='5')
a5 = b5.grid(row=8, column=0, sticky='w')
b6 = Button(frame, text='6')
a6 = b6.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky='e')
b7 = Button(frame, text='7')
a7 = b7.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky='e')
b8 = Button(frame, text='8')
a8 = b8.grid(row=6, column=2, sticky='e')
b9 = Button(frame, text='9')
a9 = b9.grid(row=7, column=2, sticky='e')
b10 = Button(frame, text='10')
a10 = b10.grid(row=8, column=2, sticky='e')

butt_list = [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10]

mainloop()
```

basically, i want to be able to show only a certain number of these buttons or to be ble to retrieve them from the list and not have them all at once

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what are you trying to accomplish? What is the issue?

Comment: basically, i want to be able to show only a certain number of these buttons or to be ble to retrieve them from the list and not have them all at once

Comment: Whenever you want to do a very similar task several times, you should use a loop. This includes creating and `grid()`ing `Button`s. Also, `c1=.grid(...` is improper syntax. I would suggest assigning the `grid()` call to a `lambda` function, but that's not actually what you need here. I suggest brushing up on the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: usually i just do b1.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='w'), but i was wondering if its possible to construct a button by doing some sort of a1+b1 or something similar, or retrieving the grided button directly from the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your comment, I'd suggest that you store the buttons in a list (as you're doing) and create a "grid mapping dictionary" that would map your grid name to indexes of requested buttons.

```
grid = {}
grid[1] = [1, 5, 9]
```

Then, if you wanted to display buttons for given grid option, just access the grid key in dictionary and loop over the buttons:

```
def buttons_for_grid(key):
    return [buttons[button] for button in grid[key]]
```

The code translates to "give me all the button objects for indexes stored in grid dictionary".

Answer (score 1):

Since the text is the only thing different you can just keep track of the text you want to display (or a list of sub-lists with [text, command/callback] if you also want a different command= for each button).

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.grid()

list_of_text=["1", "3" , "5", "6", "7"]
r=4
c=0
stick="w"
for num in list_of_text:
    ## grid on same line since you don't reference the button again
    Button(frame, text=num).grid(row=r, column=c, sticky=stick)
    r += 1
    if r > 7:
        r=4
        c += 1
        stick="e"

root.mainloop()
```